# Why am I getting different behaviour when replacing a subview created in the Interface Builder vs one created in code?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I have a cocoa `WebView` inside of an `NSSplitPane` as a subview of one of the split pane's Custom Views. This serves as a preview of some HTML content. To smooth the transition when updating the preview

1. I make an `NSImageView` from the `WebView`
2. Replace the `WebView` with the `NSImageView`
3. Load the new html into the `WebView`
4. Replace the `NSImageView` with the updated `WebView` when the html has finished loading

This is the gist of the code is:

From the header

```cpp
NSImageView *previewImageView;
NSString *content;
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *previewContainer;
@property (strong) IBOutlet WebView *previewWebView;
```

From the class

```cpp
- (void)updatePreview
{
    previewImageView = [self imageViewFromWebView:previewWebView];
    [[previewContainer animator] replaceSubview:previewWebView
        with:previewImageView];
    [[previewWebView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:content baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    [[previewContainer animator] replaceSubview:previewImageView
        with:previewWebView];
}
```

This code does not work correctly if the `WebView` is defined in the `xib` file with the referencing outlet set to the `previewWebView` and the frame load delegate set. The web view is initially shown correctly, gets swapped for the image view ok, but when swapped back does not get displayed.

If I instead define the `WebView` in code

```cpp
// inside of viewDidAppear
NSRect frame = [previewContainer frame];
NSRect webViewFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
previewWebView = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:webViewFrame];
[previewWebView setUIDelegate:self];
[previewWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
[previewWebView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
[previewContainer addSubview:previewWebView];
```

and not the interface builder, the swapping code works as expected. Any ideas as to what may be different about how I'm defining the `WebView` in code that makes it work but not when define in the interface builder?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible that Interface Builder archives the `WebView` object with some settings that are different to the defaults when creating a `WebView` programmatically.

You should probably try a few things:

```
[previewWebview setHostWindow:yourWindow];
```

This associates the `WebView` with your window. This is required if you remove the `WebView` from the window, otherwise the `WebView` will stop operating. The `WebView` will retain your window, so you should make sure you set the host window to `nil` before closing your window.

```
[previewWebView setShouldUpdateWhileOffscreen:YES];
```

This will ensure the web view actually loads content when it's offscreen.

```
[previewWebView setShouldCloseWithWindow:NO];
```

This will prevent the `WebView` from "closing" when its host window closes. If you don't do this, the `WebView` will call its `close` method, which essentially shuts it down, clearing all content and caches and preventing it from being used again. I'm pretty sure this is the default when you instantiate the `WebView` in Interface Builder, so you want to make sure it doesn't happen.

You may find that you don't need to do this if you've set the host window specifically.

Note that you will need to call `[previewWebView close]` when you do actually close your window if you do this.

Comment: I tried both of these but no luck. I noticed the frame load delegate callback gets called. So it would seem like it web view is updating or at least loading the content.

Comment: What happens if you don't use the animator proxy and just call  `[previewContainer replaceSubview:previewImageView
        with:previewWebView]`?

Comment: Same result, the web view doesn't get displayed. I also tried explicitly setting the web view frame and autoresizing mask in viewDidLoad to no avail. Basically call the same initialization code I did when I manually instantiated the web view.

Comment: I don't suppose there would be an easy way to diff two webviews, see what properties they have that are different.

Comment: Only by manually dumping their properties. Are any of the views containing the `WebView` layer-backed?

Comment: The direct parent has 'Core Animation Layer' ticked off otherwise there is no animated transition. From what I understand this is the same as doing `setWantsLayer: YES` in code.

Comment: That's almost certainly your problem. The only place it's documented is in the [animation section of the 10.5 AppKit release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes#Animation), but layer-backed `WebView` objects are not supported. This is still the case in Lion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10576/discussion-between-jeremy-raymond-and-rob-keniger)